# SQL Aggregation logic - Not sure

Tags: sql, aggregation

I am implementing the multiple separate logics between 2 tables by joining them in a view.  I need to have minimal number of views with all logics implemented.  I am struck with the following issue while implementing and need your expertise.

I had arrived to the base logic of the view as it serves as the base for most of the logics and I am to stick to it;

```
SELECT Acct_no, max(txn_date),......
FROM ACCT_CRD ac 
INNER JOIN TRNSCTN txn ON ( ac.crd_no = txn.crd_no) 
GROUP BY ACCT_NO, TO_CHAR(TXN_DATE,'YYYYMM');
```

Table_name: ACCT_CRD (This table has account and the credit card numbers with UPI on credit card numbers and a single account number can have multiple card_numbers)

Data:

```
Acct_no | Crd_no | biz_date   | Status
--------+--------+------------+--------
acct1   | crd11  | 2015-10-01 | A
--------+--------+------------+--------
acct1   | crd12  | 2015-10-02 | A
--------+--------+------------+--------
acct1   | crd13  | 2015-10-03 | A
```

Table_name: TRNSCTN (This table has transactions done through the credit cards; data doesn't reflect any actual meaning) Please note that this table has dates with 5 years, for sample, I have took for only 1 month;

Data:

```
Crd_no  |  Txn_date   | Txn_code |   crd_limit | crd_commit
--------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------
crd11   |  2015-10-02 |   10     | 10000       | 9000
--------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------
crd11   |  2015-10-02 |   10     | 10000       | 14000
--------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------
crd11   |  2015-10-02 |   20     | 10000       | 16000
--------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------
crd11   |  2015-10-03 |   20     | 10000       | 12000
--------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------
crd11   |  2015-10-05 |   20     | 10000       | 15000
--------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------
crd12   |  2015-10-03 |   10     | 20000       | 5000
--------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------
crd12   |  2015-10-03 |   20     | 20000       | 22000
--------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------
crd12   |  2015-10-04 |   30     | 20000       | 25000
--------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------
crd12   |  2015-10-04 |   30     | 20000       | 5000
--------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------
crd13   |  2015-10-04 |   30     | 25000       | 10000
```

Here, in TRNSCTN table, for each card on each day if CRD_COMMIT > CRD_LIMIT, then take the count as 1 even if there are more records with same card_no and txn_date with crd_commit >= crd_limit or crd_commit < crd_limit;

Order is not important on a given day transactions;

```
SELECT crd_no, txn_date, 
MAX(case when crd_commit > crd_limit then 1 else 0 end) day_overlimit_cnt 
FROM TRNSCTN group by crd_no, txn_date;
```

Essentially, the above data in the table transforms to

```
Crd_no | txn_date    |  day_overlimit_cnt
-------+-------------+-------------------
crd11  | 2015-10-02  | 1
-------+-------------+-------------------
crd11  | 2015-10-03  | 1
-------+-------------+-------------------
crd11  | 2015-10-05  | 1
-------+-------------+-------------------
crd12  | 2015-10-03  | 1
-------+-------------+-------------------
crd12  | 2015-10-04  | 1
-------+-------------+-------------------
crd13  | 2015-10-04  | 0
```

Then, I need to find for each card in a given month, how many times it has exceeded the day_overlimit_cnt;

```
SELECT crd_no, to_char(txn_date,'yyymm') as txn_mnth,   
SUM(day_overlimit_cnt) sum_month_ovrlmt from (select crd_no, txn_date,     
MAX(case when crd_commit > crd_limit then 1 else 0 end) day_overlimit_cnt 
FROM TRNSCTN group by crd_no, txn_date) dt_check 
GROUP BY crd_no, to_char(txn_date,'yyymm');
```

The data from the above query will be

```
Crd_no | txn_mnth | sum_month_ovrlmt
-------+----------+-----------------
crd11  | 201510   | 3
-------+----------+-----------------
crd12  | 201510   | 2
-------+----------+-----------------
crd13  | 201510   | 0
```

And then finally find the max(sum_month_ovrlmt) at account level by joining the above one to ACCT_CRD;

```
SELECT acct_no, MAX(sum_month_ovrlmt) acct_mnth_ovrlmt 
FROM ACCT_CRD ac 
JOIN (SELECT crd_no, to_char(txn_date,'yyymm') as txn_mnth,     
SUM(day_overlimit_cnt) sum_month_ovrlmt FROM (SELECT crd_no, txn_date, MAX(case when crd_commit > crd_limit then 1 else 0 end) day_overlimit_cnt FROM TRNSCTN group by crd_no, txn_date) dt_check GROUP BY crd_no, to_char(txn_date,'yyymm')) dt_dt_check dt on (ac.cr_no = dt.crd_no) GROUP BY acct_no;
```

Final output:

```
Acct_no | acct_mnth_ovrlmt
--------+-----------------
acct1   | 3
```

How to embed the above logic into the following base query;  That is how to derive acct_mnth_ovrlmt without affecting the other columns data in the select part.

```
SELECT Acct_no, max(txn_date),...... 
FROM ACCT_CRD ac 
INNER JOIN   TRNSCTN txn ON ( ac.crd_no = txn.crd_no) 
GROUP BY ACCT_NO, TO_CHAR(TXN_DATE,'YYYYMM');
```

Thanks in advance for your time.  As a last resort, I will try to embed the above derived code until aggregation of cards into the base query and will try it out.

Greetings Gordon Linoff,
Thank you for your post.  I need the distinct conditional count as you mentioned at card_number level.  And as account_number can have more than 1 card_number, I need to find out the max(overlimit_cnt) at account_level;
i.e., say if the distinct conditional count is as

```
crd11  |  3
crd12  |  2
crd13  |  0
```

As all these card_numbers belong to acct1, need to get the max(overlimit_cnt) of the above card_numbers; i.e.,

```
acct   |   3
```

I guess I need to again have another join to the same table with group by on different columns as

```
SELECT Acct_no, max(txn_date),......,MAX(day_overlimit_cnt)
FROM ACCT_CRD ac 
INNER JOIN   TRNSCTN txn ON ( ac.crd_no = txn.crd_no) 
INNER JOIN  ( SELECT CRD_NO, TO_CHAR(TXN_DATE,'YYYYMM') AS TXN_DATE_Y,
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN crd_commit > crd_limit then TXN_DATE end))  day_overlimit_cnt  from TRNSCTN GROUP BY CRD_NO, TO_CHAR(TXN_DATE,'YYYYMM')) TRNSCTN_OVRLMT ON (TRNSCTN.CRD_NO=TRNSCTN_OVRLMT.CRD_NO AND TO_CHAR(TRNSCTN.TXN_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')=TRNSCTN_OVRLMT.TXN_DATE_Y) GROUP BY ACCT_NO, TO_CHAR(TXN_DATE,'YYYYMM');
```

Can I avoid new join TRNSCTN_OVRLMT and derive above value.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a little hard to follow, but I think you just want conditional count distinct:

```
SELECT Acct_no, max(txn_date),
       COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN crd_commit > crd_limit THEN txn_date END)) as DaysOverLimit
FROM ACCT_CRD ac INNER JOIN
     TRNSCTN txn
     ON ac.crd_no = txn.crd_no 
GROUP BY ACCT_NO, TO_CHAR(TXN_DATE,'YYYYMM');
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff;  I have went up with the above edited code in my post with additional join processing;  Thank you for your logic DISTINCT (CASE WHEN crd_commit > crd_limit then TXN_DATE end)    Good learning